# Request fails if json response contains accented character

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.3, Mysql and Nginx on Ubuntu.

My Action is:

```
return \Response::json($resultados, 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) ;
```

print_r of $results is:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [rua] => jardim pedreiras
        [cep] => 14405024
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [rua] => vila chico julio
        [cep] => 14405233
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [rua] => jardim pedreiras
        [cep] => 14405037
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [rua] => jardim roselândia
        [cep] => 14405060
    )
)
```

The problem is "roselândia". I change this value and it works.

Comment: Can you provide the error from either the logs or the failing response in your navigator?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I changed the title to make it more general, so that others with the same problem can more easily find your question. I also reformatted the output, so that it's easier to read. Finally I removed the nginx tag, as it's very unlikely to be relevant to the problem. Good luck!